# Perl: Can't pass question mark as command line argument

Tags: bash, perl

I can't pass a question mark character into a Perl script. It comes out as the letter "t" instead.

```
./myscript foo
print $ARGV[0]; # prints foo

./myscript ?
print $ARGV[0]; # prints t

./myscript "?"
print $ARGV[0]; # prints ?

./myscript ??
print $ARGV[0]; # prints ?? (multiple question marks work)

./myscript ^
print $ARGV[0]; # prints ^; other special characters work too

./myscript foo?
print $ARGV[0]; # prints foo?
```

I can't find an explanation for this anywhere. The reason I want to pass in a question mark is so my script has an easy help option. Other special characters work, as does quoting the question mark, as does a question mark mixed in with another string. It's just a single, naked question mark that doesn't.

I'm calling the script via the Bash shell. I'm not 100% positive this is a Perl issue

---

Update: now that this question is answered, I'm suddenly realizing: is this the reason that most command line arguments have a dash in front of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a file named `t` in the directory in which you are running your script.  The shell treats a question mark (`?`) as a single character and expands it prior to passing the argument to your script.  If you have a file named `xx`, for example, then running your script with `??` would print "xx".

If you quote your script's argument, no shell expansion occurs and passing `?` or `*` or `??` remain uninterpreted.

Comment: I did in fact have a file named "t" in the directory. I use files named "t" as temporary scratch notes files.

Answer (score 3):

The question mark `?` is a shell metacharacter that is used for glob expansion. It is a placeholder for a single character, similar to `.` in a regex. E.g. If I have files `a1.txt a2.txt b1.txt`, then the glob pattern `a?.txt` will match the `a1.txt` and `a2.txt` but not `b1.txt`.

The following shell metacharacters must always be escaped or quoted when they are part of a command line argument:

```
|  &  ;  <  >  (  )  $  `  \  "  '  <space>  <tab>  <newline>
```

These characters must sometimes be escaped:

```
*   ?   [   #   ˜   =   %
```

Additionally the symbols `! {  } [[ ]]` are reserved words.

(taken from the [POSIX shell language description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). Bash is mostly POSIX-compatible.)